# Bootstrap. Scroll link menu and fix the navbar at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position, navbar, sticky

How can I do the following:

1. I want to have sticky nav bar - fixed navbar - (let's call it NavbarMain) on top of the page, but
2. when the page is not scrolled I want to have just on top of NavbarMain a row with some links - linkRow - (maybe like a second menu) that is not sticky/fixed.

so when the page is not scrolled I have

```
linkRow
NavbarMain
```

after the page is scrolled I have:

```
NavbarMain
```

the linkRow will scroll and NavbarMain will replace it and stick to the top.

Basically I want something similar with:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp
notice that when you scroll, the top part is hidden and the menu take place? How can I implement that in bootstrap.

Thank you

Comment: what you have tried so far? show us some codes.

Comment: Well, I have the navbar: `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top scrolled">
  <div class=" container-fluid">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>` I need to add the top link somehow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Set up the affix plugin

You need to use [the affix plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix). It's a standard Bootstrap component.

This plugin makes the block fixed when the page is scrolled on the `data-offset-top` pixels:

> Pixels to [offset from screen](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix-options) when calculating position of scroll.

So you don't need to use the `.navbar-fixed-top` class. But you have to set some CSS properties for fixed navbar by the .navbar.affix class:

- The `top: 0;` property sets the vertical position of the fixed navbar;
- Properties `left: 0; right; 0;` force the navbar to expand to the width of the screen.

#### Avoid of page jumping

When the navbar becomes fixed it loses its space on the page. You've got two troubles at this moment:

- A text below the navbar jumps up and hides under the navbar.
- Page height decreases. If it becomes less than the height of the window, the page scrolls down and the plugin returns the navbar to its place. It looks as if   the navbar does not allow the page to go up.

So you need a CSS trick. Add `margin-bottom` to the block before the navbar and add negative `margin-top` to the navbar. The value of both margins must be equal to the height of the unfixed navbar.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.above {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.navbar {
  margin-top: -70px;
}
.navbar.affix {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container above">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="70">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>  

<div class="container">
  <p>Paragraph 1.</p><p>Paragraph 2.</p><p>Paragraph 3.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p><p>Paragraph.</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ClaudiuHardalau I've improved my solution. Please check new code and description.

Comment: Thank you @GlebKemarsky!

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a plugin called "Affix" that offers, I think, what you want.

Just include [this Javascript file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/affix.js) in your HTML:

And read the [documentation here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) for instructions on how to use it.

This example from the docs:

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60">
</div>
```

should keep 60 pixels of the div visible at the top of the screen when you scroll past it.

Comment: `60` is not about percents. It's a [number of pixels](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix-options): `Pixels to offset from screen when calculating position of scroll. `